# How to get all fields with filtering on the related set in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**I have Three model defined. I want to filter Get specific user and get all related fields in the result set. For example, I want to get supplierInfo and company info of that user.**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_email= models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=254)
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    staff=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    admin=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    role_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    supplier=models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE) ....

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name= models.CharField(('company name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    company_id  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('company')
        verbose_name_plural = ('company')
        db_table = "company"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_name= models.CharField(('supplier name'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    supplier_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('supplier')
        verbose_name_plural = ('supplier')
        db_table = "supplier"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplier_name
```

I Have tried this

```
 userInfo=User.objects.filter(user_id__exact=user.user_id).get()
 userRelated= Supplier.objects.filter(supplier_id__exact=userInfo.supplier_id).get() 
 companyRelated=Company.objects.filter(company_id__exact=userRelated.company_id).get()
```

I am getting expected result But I dont think it is the best way. I want to merge three queries and get the result in one object . I am new in django so please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a one to one relationship by defining a foreign key.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/
The documentation is really well written and i suggest you take a look for yourself.

If you do this you will have access to the related table when using the typical django orm methods.